# VBA Excel реакция на форму.

Tags: vba, excel

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть `UserForm` с двумя переключателями (`OptionButton`) и, естественно кнопкой запуска. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе одного из переключателя, программа, ну скажем, вставляла определенную цифру в определенную ячейку? Никак не могу найти документацию по данному вопросу. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:
Пусть на форме есть два переключателя `obOptionButton1` и `obOptionButton2`. Добавим для них обработчики события *клик*, это делается очень просто, в коде формы нужно определить функции `obOptionButton1_Click` и `obOptionButton2_Click` соответственно:

```
Private Sub obOptionButton1_Click()
    If obOptionButton1.Value Then
        'действия при выборе obOptionButton1
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Имя_Листа").Activate
        Range("A1").Value = "Значение ячейки в любом формате"
    End If
End Sub
```

Подробнее можете посмотреть [тут](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Create_User_Forms_in_Microsoft_Excel/629.html).

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение:
как понял, кнопка запуска предназначена для запуска процедуры записи, поэтому:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
```

Для вставки значения не обязательно активировать лист.